# Uniform bound on Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is from Fourier Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, section 3, exercise 19. I am trying to prove that $\sum_{0<|n|\le N} e^{inx}/n$ is uniformly bounded in $N$ and $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$. Following the suggested approach, I start with
$$\frac 1 {2i} \sum_{0<|n|\le N} \frac{e^{inx}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \frac 1 2 \int_0^x \! (D_N(t) -1)\, dt$$

where $D_N(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^N e^{inx}$ is the Dirichlet kernel. The authors then suggest that I use the fact that $\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin t}{t} dt<\infty$, which I did prove in an earlier exercise. I don't see how the integral in the above display is related to $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$, and I would appreciate a *hint* if possible (rather than a full answer).

I have tried writing $D_N(t) = \frac{\sin((N+\frac 1 2)t)}{\sin(t/2)}$ and then making various substitutions in the integration but I don't see, in particular, how a $t$ would ever appear in the denominator. I could of course use an inequality at some point to get a $t$ in the denominator, but a later question seems to indicate that equality is what is expected here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following hint meets the requirement.

By the formula you give in your post, it is enough to show that $\int_0^x D_N(t)\, dt$ is uniformly bounded with respect to $N$ and $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$. Setting $\lambda:=2N+1$ and replacing $t$ by $t/2$ in the integral, it is again enough to show that $$\int_0^{u} \frac{\sin(\lambda t)}{\sin t}\, dt $$ is uniformly bounded with respect to $\lambda\in (1,\infty)$ and to $u\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Now, here is the hint: show separately that $\int_0^u \frac{\sin(\lambda t)}{t}\, dt$ and $\int_0^u \left( \frac1{\sin t}-\frac1t\right) \sin(\lambda t)\, dt$ are uniformly bounded wrt $\lambda$ and $u$. For the first integral, this should follow immediately from the obvious change of variable; and for the second one, a brutal estimate should work.

Comment: I understand the hint, but I"m not sure if this is what was intended because in the next question we are supposed to use the results from this question (in particular, the representation $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \frac 1 2 \int_0^x D_N(t)-1 dt$) to find that $$\max_{0<x\le\pi/N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \int_0^\pi \frac {\sin t}{t} dt,$$
which I am starting to have my doubts about - calculating the derivative one finds that the maximum occurs at $x=\pi/(N+1)$, but
$$\int_0^{\pi/(N+1)} (D_N(t)-1) \, dt \ne \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{t} \, dt$$

Comment: Right now, I don't see the link with the question of your post... I mean, in the problem from Stein-Karachi

Comment: True, your answer does address my original question, thanks!

Comment: I was not saying that to have my answer accepted (but thanks for that, of course). I was just curious about the problem: what do they (Stein & Shakarchi) have in mind, after all?

Comment: This is exercise 19, and as I mention they ask you to prove in exercise 20 that 
$$\max_{0<x\le\pi/N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \int_0^\pi \frac {\sin t}{t} dt,$$
although I believe this is a typo, and instead should be taken as the limit as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: How about this (very similar to your suggestion): To show that $\int_0^x D_N(t) \, dt$ is uniformly bounded in $x$ and $N$, note that for any $x$ we have by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma that
$$\int_0^x \frac {\sin((N+1/2)t)}{\sin(t/2)} - \frac{2\sin((N+1/2)t)}{t}\, dt \to 0\quad\text{as }N\to\infty.$$
Moreover, 
$$\int_0^x \frac{\sin((N+1/2)t)}{t}\,dt = \int_0^{(N+1/2)x} \frac{\sin u}{u} \, du \to \frac{\pi}2\quad\text{as }N\to\infty,$$
therefore
$$\int_0^x\frac{\sin((N+1/2)t)}{\sin(t/2)}\,dt\to\pi\quad\text{as }N\to\infty,$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: Looks OK, but you have to be careful about the uniformity wrt $x$.

Comment: I think Riemann-Lebesgue handles that automatically, specifically it is stated in my text as: if $f(\theta)$ is an integrable function on the circle, then $\hat{f}(n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and in particular therefore
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\! f(\theta) \sin(N\theta)\, d\theta\to0\quad\text{as}\quad N\to\infty$$
and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\! f(\theta) \cos(N\theta)\, d\theta\to0\quad\text{as}\quad N\to\infty$$,
so noting that if $f(\theta)$ is integrable so is $\chi_{[0,x]}(\theta)f(\theta)$, we have that for $x\in[0,2\pi]$ we can replace $2\pi$ by $x$ in the above expressions and have the same result.

Comment: But still, you have $\int_0^x$; so I'm not quite sure the uniformity is a direct consequence of RL.

Comment: Agreed, uniformity is not implied, thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15042/discussion-between-process91-and-etienne).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Etienne does address the specific question I asked, but it did not help address the next question, so I didn't feel it was what the authors had intended. Instead, I think they were looking for something like this:

First, an argument is needed which shows that for $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$, $|\int_0^x\!( D_N(t)-1)\, dt|$ achieves its maximum at $x=\pi/(N+1)$. Then revert to the previous representation of the Fourier series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^N x\frac{\sin nx}{nx}\le\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\pi}{N+1} \frac{\sin (n \pi/(N+1))}{n\pi/(N+1)}$$

Taking the limit as $N\to\infty$ gives an integral very closely related to what they suggested considering.